# Post with Twitter API and PHP

Tags: post, twitter

I am new to Twitter API and in twitter in general so I have some questions. I have a web site and I want to add a button for sharing a message (for example "Hello World", taken from my site) to a user's twitter page. 
First of all I have created an application in twitter, call myTwitterApp and I want to post through this. When the user clicks the button I want to see the authentication page, for login, and then after login I want to see my message inside the editable input, being able to be changed my the user. And finally I want the user to post it by clicking the tweet button, but continue saying that the post was "via myTwitterApp".

Does anyone have an idea how to do it or how to search about it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some experience with the twitter api lately, but not comprehensively. so I can only give you some kind of direction, and hopefully this will help you. So the idea is that you should understand how the Oauth protocol works, steps like requestToken->accessToken->api calls.  there is a tutorial for beginners here http://oauth.net/documentation/getting-started/, you shold take a look.  if you have manage to go through the oauth authentication, then you should be able to call the POST method which you can post contents to Twitter. you can search for Twitter oauth api, there are a bunch of them online. grab one and use it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have managed to do the authentication and the post. My problem is that with the post the message goew directly to the timeline page of my twitter while I what to edit it first and then post it. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: in that case, what I can think of is to use textarea in a popup window before calling post.

Comment: You mean to do something of my own. Not using something of the API. Do you think that in this case, if I click the tweet button it would say via mytwitterApp? Cause I think that if I do it this way then it would say via Twitter Button.

Comment: As an example. I want to do what the TweetMeme does but through my application and without saying retweet, but just Tweet.